# return name for object from cxf jax-rs call

Tags: json, cxf, jax-rs

I have

```
Config {
  int a;
  ....
}
```

and my service as

```
MySvc {

@Produces(JSON)
    public Config getConfigData() {
      return config;
    }
}
```

I want json wrapped with object name

```
var MyConfig = {"a":"value" }
```

Is this possible ?

currently it returns

```
{"a":"value"}
```

Comment: what is `BBXConfig` in your example? where did it come from?

Comment: @yegor256 Its js variable. I want such output. But it seems i misunderstood. This isn't json. Its javascript variable.

Comment: looks like your question needs refactoring. now it has no sense, in JAX-RS context. I voted to close